# Angular otherwise not working

Tags: angularjs

So on load to the base page, I'm expecting the page to redirect to: http://myurl.com/index.php#/search

Currently nothing happens...any ideas?

```
 <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="appDep">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-route.js"></script>

<script>

var app = angular.module('appDep', ['ngRoute']);

app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/search/:sig?', {
         templateUrl: 'blablabla',
         controller : 'notYetCreated'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/search'
    });
} ]);

app.controller('notYetCreated', function($scope,$log,$http,$q,$routeParams, $location) {
    console.log('test')
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

    HI


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="blablabla">

    TEST
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to set up the template with blablabla.html

Comment: Take a look at the developer windows to see if there are any errors

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Well what I'm expecting is if I go to http://myurl.com/index.php it should default to: http://myurl.com/index.php#/search

Comment: Whats the point of downvoting this when it was an actual issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<div ng-view></div>`

Comment: $routeProvider works with `ng-view` directive to display the right view. It doesn't actually do an HTTP redirect. For an HTTP redirect you'd need to use `$location.href`

Comment: That was a great catch.. using an ng-view for routing is obvious and op had missed it and no body noticed that. :D